# XmlSerializing only the base object

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, serialization

Currently I am trying to write a set of two classes: one (BackgroundManagerSettings) which will hold all the variables that I wish to save when the program is closed, and another (BackgroundManager) which contains methods and variables that will only be needed during the runtime.

Code:

```
public class BackgroundManager : BackgroundManagerSettings
    {
    //Example
    private string _LastName;
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LastName;
        }

        set
        {
            this._LastName = value;
        }
    }

    public BackgroundManager()
    {
        this.LastName = "Smith";
    }

    public static BackgroundManager Load(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundManager));

        LoopAgain:

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                return Serializer.Deserialize(Reader) as BackgroundManager;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(Writer, new BackgroundManager() as BackgroundManagerSettings);
                Writer.Close();
            }

            goto LoopAgain;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            File.Delete(filename);

            goto LoopAgain;
        }
    }

    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundManager));

        using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(Writer, this as BackgroundManagerSettings);
            Writer.Close();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BackgroundManagerSettings
{
    //Example
    private string _FirstName;
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._FirstName;
        }

        set
        {
            this._FirstName = value;
        }
    }

    public BackgroundManagerSettings()
    {
        this.FirstName = "Joe";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BackgroundManager Manager = BackgroundManager.Load("temp.Xml");
Manager.Save("temp.Xml");
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BackgroundManager xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
     <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</BackgroundManager>
```

My current problem is that when I use the Save() Method it serializes the fields of BackgroundManager as well as the fields of BackgroundManagerSettings. How do I make it so it only serializes the fields of BackgroundManagerSettings? Any help or links to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mark all the public members of the base class that you don't want to be serialized with [XmlIgnore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: This would be my last resort. I would much rather have to not manually set each member. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Else, Do not inhert from BackgroundManagerSettings.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class BackgroundManager : BackgroundManagerSettings
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PropertyToSerialize { get; set; }
}
```

Add the DataMember decoration to all of the properties that you want included.

Comment: This for WCF I think. Not for XmlSerialization

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found a method that works how I want it to thanks for the advice.

```
 public static BackgroundManager Load(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundManager));

        LoopAgain:

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                return Serializer.Deserialize(Reader) as BackgroundManager;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            XmlSerializer BaseSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundManagerSettings));

            using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                BaseSerializer.Serialize(Writer, new BackgroundManager().ToBase());
                Writer.Close();
            }

            goto LoopAgain;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            File.Delete(filename);

            goto LoopAgain;
        }
    }

    public void Save(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BackgroundManagerSettings));

        using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(Writer, this.ToBase());
            Writer.Close();
        }
    }

    private dynamic ToBase()
    {
        var Temp = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(BackgroundManagerSettings));

        FieldInfo[] Fields = Temp.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (FieldInfo x in Fields)
        {
            x.SetValue(Temp, x.GetValue(this));
        }

        return Temp;
    }
```